# Next step for learning opengl es android?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I completed some opengl es tutorial on net. I have now some basic understanding about opengl es. Ive done some particle stuff and the basic triangle with 3 color and loading some texture on it. Now im not sure where to go next. After learning the basics what is the next step on learning opengl es? should i go to opengl only? Because i havent seen a tutorial on opengl es from beginner to advance stuff. I am looking for a link where it shows an example rather than a code only. I am also okay if you could give me some book title?

Comment: The third article here is specific to Android: http://montgomery1.com/opengl/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go through the [OpenGL tutorial guide](http://www.sci.brooklyn.cuny.edu/~sklar/teaching/s12/cisc3650/labs/android-openGL-ES-1.0.pdf) also [here Open GL ES 2.0](http://www.jayway.com/2013/05/09/opengl-es-2-0-tutorial-for-android-part-i-getting-started/) is the basic to advance tutorial with explanation tutorial which will be more useful to you.

Comment: hmmm I'm much more interested in 2.0.. Do you have that link?

Comment: @user31546 I have already mentioned it in my answer check out.

Comment: @GrIsHu Hi... Do you have an idea about recording frames that are being drawn on Surface of GLSurfaceView as a video? what I am doing is getting raw data from the Camera preview in `onPreviewFrame()` callback, converting that YUV data to RGBA format and applying effects like blur, gaussian,negative,grayscale etc etc and displaying it on GLSurfaceView using OpenGL. Now I want to record each frame that is being drawn on Surface as a Video...

Comment: @GrIsHu You will get clear idea about my question when you see this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dama.camera2&hl=en...

Comment: @GopalRao No, Haven't come across this kind of work before.